# requests.get(imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png) is not working?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am sorry if I sound like idiot. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
r = requests.get('imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png')
```

But this command is not working. I am getting error:

MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png?

It is working fine for other URLs. In fact, I tried opening this URL manually and this worked. Why so? Interestingly, when I try to open the same link with webbrowser module, I faced no problem.

Comment: Is it working fine for other URL's that don't start with an http:// ? Note that the fact that it works for a browser is because the browser adds an http to it.

Comment: I kinda gives it away in the error doesn't it? ;p

Comment: Kind of strange the last time this error came up [was also regarding xkcd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770213/no-schema-supplied-and-other-errors-with-using-requests-get)

Comment: Is it mandatory to give an URL starting with http:// (or www) in Requests? I mean when I supply the URL as 'www.example.com', it creates no problem.

Comment: @JonClements Somehow this link didn't appear when I searched for the question. Like other guy, Automate The Boring Stuff book inspired me to download comics from XKCD. :)

But yeah, I think I have to use http:// part. This is slightly irritating though.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify protocol:

```
r = requests.get('http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

An URL has a schema. Like HTTP. But as the error message says, your URL does not have a schema and is thus invalid. Solution: Supply schema.

```
r = requests.get('http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png')
```

(Also, the error message already tells you this solution ;)

Comment: I would have done this. Problem is I am scrapping the webpage of XKCD and in its HTML code, the link to cartoon is given without any http:// part.

Comment: No it isn't. In the web page they are linked as `src="//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png"`, which is a specialty HTML syntax. The double-slash (`//`) tells the browser to access the resource with the same schema it accessed the web page embedding the resource. That way you can have the same web page served via HTTP and HTTPS, without changing the contents. Your app would need to emulate this behaviour (e.g. prepend HTTP/HTTPS).

Comment: That cleared some issues. But why would webbrowser module open this link without any hassle?

Comment: If I paste that - `//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png` - into my browser, it doesn't work. It assumes that the schema should be `file`. If you paste it without the two slashes (`imgs.xkcd.com/comics/frankenstein.png`) almost every browser will assume you meant to access it via HTTP.