# Can I click on several URLs and get text using HTML tags through beautifulsoup and requests library?

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a question regarding using beautifulsoup and requests in a  python for-loop to scrape data from several pages. Basically, I'm trying to get a list of job titles, summaries, links and descriptions from indeed as part of a test (I can't use API).

Here's the link : https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=data+scientist&start=

Here is the part of the website that I'm trying to scrape (it's the  that stores every non-sponsored search result).

```
 <div class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row result clickcard" 
id="p_a7f43b014b2d324d" data-jk="a7f43b014b2d324d" data-tn- 
component="organicJob" data-tu="">
<h2 id="jl_a7f43b014b2d324d" class="jobtitle">
     <a href="/rc/clk? 
jk=a7f43b014b2d324d&amp;fccid=deadcc7ca64ae08b&amp;vjs=3" 
target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow" onmousedown="return 
rclk(this,jobmap[4],0);" onclick="setRefineByCookie([]); return 
rclk(this,jobmap[4],true,0);" title="Data Scientist - Mumbai" 
class="turnstileLink" data-tn-element="jobTitle"><b>Data</b> 
<b>Scientist</b> - Mumbai</a>
    - <span class="new">new</span></h2>
```

I've written a for loop that grabs the everything except the link:

```
pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

for page in pages:

    source = requests.get('https://www.indeed.co.in/jobsq=data+scientist&start='.format()).text
     soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')


    for jobs in soup.findAll(class_='result'):

    try:
        Job_title = jobs.a.text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        Job_title = None
    try:
        company = jobs.span.text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        company = None
    try:
        summary = jobs.find('span', class_='summary').text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        summary = None
    try:
        link = jobs.find('href', class_='jobtitle').text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        link= None
```

Right now, I get all the elements I require, except the link.

My questions are:

a. within the same for loop (or a different way) How can I grab the link for each job title as well?

b. How can I use requests to click on each link, and grab the job summary text? it's stored in a class="jobsearch-JobComponent-description icl-u-xs-mt--md"

Any help regarding any of these would be amazing, I'm very new to this. Thank you!

edit: 
[photo of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idotk.png)

edit 2- The traceback error I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saharsh/Desktop/Kaggle Competition/Data_Science.ipynb", line 42, in 
    source = requests.get(r['link'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 498, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 441, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 309, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 383, in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?

Comment: Use `'a.turnstileLink'` to select the links. Then for each link submit a new request to get the job summary.

Comment: there is an error in your url, you forgot the `?` between `https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs` and `q=data...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So several think are not working in your snippet.
First, to get the link, you have to focus BeautifulSoup on the `a` tag.

Then, you don't need all theses try except.

Here is a piece of code, including the second call to get the summary text:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

for page in pages:

    source = requests.get('https://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=data+scientist&start='.format()).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    results = []
    for jobs in soup.findAll(class_='result'):
        result = {
                    'job_title': '',
                    'company': '',
                    'summary': '',
                    'link': '',
                    'summary_text': ''
                }


        job_title = jobs.find('h2', {'class': 'jobtitle'})
        if job_title and job_title.find('a'):
            result['job_title'] = job_title.find('a').get('title')
            result['link'] = "https://www.indeed.co.in{0}".format(job_title.find('a').get('href'))
        #else:
        #    print("no job title for ", jobs)


        company_span = jobs.find('span', {'class': 'company'})
        if company_span:
            result['company'] = company_span.get_text()

        summary = jobs.find('span', class_='summary')
        if summary:
            result['summary'] = summary.get_text()

        results.append(result)

for r in results:
    #print(r['link'])
    source = requests.get(r['link'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')

    description = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'jobsearch-JobComponent-description'})
    if description:
        r['summary_text'] = description.get_text()

print(results)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'company': '\n        DataMetica',
  'job_title': 'Big-Data, Analytics Opportunities - Tech Savvy Talented '
               'Freshers',
  'link': 'https://www.indeed.co.in/rc/clk?jk=72e59a4376e3c7f1&fccid=f753310165e7a862&vjs=3',
  'summary': '\n'
             '            Datametica supports the fresh minds to engage with '
             'evolving tools and technologies working on Big data, Data '
             'Science, Information Analytics and related...',
  'summary_text': 'Pune, MaharashtraFresherJob Description\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Experience - 0 to 1 Years\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Selected candidates would get training and opportunity to '
                  'work on live projects in Big-Data, Analytics & Data '
                  'Science\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Candidates from Top Ranked Colleges or Premier Institutes '
                  'like IIT, NIT, REC, IIIT are preferred.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Do you have knowledge on RDBMS Systems like Oracle, MY SQL, '
                  'Teradata and experience in solving analytical problems? Did '
                  'you use Java, C and C++ for your projects?\n'
                  '\n'
                  'If yes, then just apply with us.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Datametica supports the fresh minds to engage with evolving '
                  'tools and technologies working on Big data, Data Science, '
                  'Information Analytics and related technologies like Hadoop, '
                  'Java, NoSQL.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Added Advantage if you possess:\n'
                  'B.E/ B. Tech in Computer Science (graduated in 2016 & '
                  '2017)\n'
                  'Minimum 60% in Graduation\n'
                  'Good Communication Skills\n'
                  '0 to 1 Year experience'},

...
...
 {'company': '\n\n        Barclays',
  'job_title': 'Junior Data Scientist',
  'link': 'https://www.indeed.co.in/rc/clk?jk=2473a92840979437&fccid=057abf3fd357e717&vjs=3',
  'summary': '\n'
             '            Junior Data Scientist. Junior Data Scientist - '
             '90227028. Experience with the Python Data Science/Machine '
             'learning stack....',
  'summary_text': 'Pune, MaharashtraJunior Data Scientist - 90227028\n'
                  'Primary Location:IN-Maharashtra-Pune\n'
                  'Job Type:Permanent/Regular\n'
                  'Posting Range:3 Apr 2019 - 11 Apr 2019\n'
                  'Description\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Job Title: Junior Data Scientist\n'
                  'Location: Pune\n'
                  '\n'
                  'The Technology Chief Data Office exists to support and '
                  'enhance Barclays’ Technology function by leveraging its '
                  'most important asset: data. Within this, the mission '
                  'statement of the Data Science team is to enable Barclays to '
                  'react to things before they happen: to drive predictive '
                  'decision making by leveraging data on Technology, People, '
                  'and Process. We employ machine learning and artificial '
                  'intelligence models to discover the hidden patterns in the '
                  'data which describes Barclays, and use these to make '
                  'measured predictions. By understanding the rules which '
                  'govern the future evolution of any given resource, we can '
                  'make the right decisions in the present, driving matters '
                  'towards the business’ desired end goals.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'What will you be doing?\n'
                  'Develop machine learning and artificial intelligence '
                  'solutions as part of the project roadmap of the team\n'
                  'Support the team in balancing strategic project work with '
                  'incoming needs for data-driven methods.\n'
                  'Be agile, quick-thinking, and practical.\n'
                  'Evangelise for solving problems through Data across the '
                  'bank – contribute to the presence of our team in horizontal '
                  'bank-wide forums.\n'
                  'Contribute a creative and analytical/technical viewpoint of '
                  'problems\n'
                  'Support the team in supplying stakeholders with whatever '
                  'supplementary material they may require in order to get our '
                  'output into large-scale production.\n'
                  'Apply technical and analytical expertise to exploring and '
                  'examining data with the goal of discovering patterns and '
                  'previously hidden insights, which in turn can provide a '
                  'competitive advantage or address a pressing business '
                  'problem.\n'
                  'Implement model output within infrastructure, business '
                  'tools and workflow processes: turn data into something that '
                  'drives action within the business.\n'
                  'Leverage knowledge of mathematical and statistical '
                  'concepts, to bridge the gap between technologists and '
                  'mathematicians, ensuring software solutions meet business '
                  'goals.\n'
                  'What we’re looking for:\n'
                  'Experience solving real-world problems and creating value '
                  'through the end-to-end, productionised application of Data '
                  'Science, Machine Learning, and Artificial Intelligence '
                  'methods.\n'
                  'Experience with the Python Data Science/Machine learning '
                  'stack.\n'
                  'Master’s level degree in Science, Technology, Engineering, '
                  'Mathematics, or other relevant field, and associated '
                  'mathematical/analytical skills\n'
                  'Excellent interpersonal, written and verbal communication '
                  'skills is a must\n'
                  'Good presentation skills with ability to explain '
                  'sophisticated solution in layman terms\n'
                  'Skills that will help you in the role:\n'
                  'Experience using cloud solutions such as AWS/GCP\n'
                  'Experience using parallelised data storage and computation '
                  'solutions such as Hadoop\n'
                  'Experience with TensorFlow, neural networks, xgboost, nltk\n'
                  'Where will you be working?\n'
                  'PuneBarclays recently announced the creation of a new '
                  'world-class campus at Gera Commerzone located in Kharadi. '
                  'All Pune based roles will eventually start to move to this '
                  'new campus starting September 2019. In the run up to that, '
                  'during the course of 2018, there may be transitory '
                  'movements of some roles to other temporary sites. Please '
                  'speak with your recruiter about the specific location plans '
                  'for your role.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'For further information on EVP, please click on the link '
                  'below\n'
                  'https://now.barclays.com/WCP/content/intranet/en/functions/operations-and-technology/global-service-centre/EVP.html\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Be More at Barclays\n'
                  'At Barclays, each day is about being more – as a '
                  'professional, and as a person. ‘Be More @ Barclays’ '
                  'represents our core promise to all current and future '
                  'employees. It’s the characteristic that we want to be '
                  'associated with as an employer, and at the heart of every '
                  'employee experience. We empower our colleagues to Be More '
                  'Globally Connected, working on international projects that '
                  'improve the way millions of customers handle their '
                  'finances. Be More Inspired by working alongside the most '
                  'talented people in the industry, and delivering imaginative '
                  'new solutions that are redefining the future of finance. Be '
                  'More Impactful by having the opportunity to work on '
                  'cutting-edge projects, and Be More Valued for who you are.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Interested and want to know more about Barclays? Visit '
                  'home.barclays/who-we-are/ for more details.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Our Values\n'
                  'Everything we do is shaped by the five values of Respect, '
                  'Integrity, Service, Excellence and Stewardship. Our values '
                  'inform the foundations of our relationships with customers '
                  'and clients, but they also shape how we measure and reward '
                  'the performance of our colleagues. Simply put, success is '
                  'not just about what you achieve, but about how you achieve '
                  'it.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Our Diversity\n'
                  'We aim to foster a culture where individuals of all '
                  'backgrounds feel confident in bringing their whole selves '
                  'to work, feel included and their talents are nurtured, '
                  'empowering them to contribute fully to our vision and '
                  'goals.\n'
                  '\n'
                  'Our Benefits\n'
                  'Our customers are unique. The same goes for our colleagues. '
                  "That's why at Barclays we offer a range of benefits, "
                  'allowing every colleague to choose the best options for '
                  'their personal circumstances. These include a competitive '
                  'salary and pension, health care and all the tools, '
                  'technology and support to help you become the very best you '
                  'can be. We are proud of our dynamic working options for '
                  'colleagues. If you have a need for flexibility, then please '
                  'discuss this with us.'}]
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your code and the output im getting doesn't give me a job title, but prints out a lot of the actual HTML like so : 
no job title for  <div class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row result " data-ci="272545156" data-empn="1804993680870938"

etc.
What do you think could be going wrong? I'll edit the question and add a screenshot of the output.

Comment: @Harshmallo You should comment the differents `print` and print the `results` list. See my edit

Comment: this is really helpful. I tried running it, and I get a traceback error - i've updated the original question with the entire error. It's weird because when I run the print command right before source = requests.get(r['link']), it works just fine. but at source = requests.get(r['link']) it says that there's a traceback and suggests adding an https//.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770213/no-schema-supplied-and-other-errors-with-using-requests-get
Is my answer good enough to be accepted?